# Why am I not getting any verbose output in my C# PowerShell streams?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have instantiated a C# PowerShell object and added scripts like so:

```cs
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(@"& ""filename.ps1"" ""machine5"" ""stop"" ");
Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
```

For reference, here are the contents of filename.ps1:

```bsh
param([string] $middleTier, [string] $mode)

Write-Verbose "This does appear"
if($mode -eq "stop") {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $middleTier -ScriptBlock {
        Write-Verbose "This does not appear"
        Stop-Service -Name "ARealService" -Force -Verbose
    }
    iisreset $middleTier /stop
}
```

However, after a call to `ps.Invoke()`, all of my `ps.Streams` collections are empty.  I know for a fact that this script writes to the verbose stream when run, but the C# Powershell object does not seem to capture any of it.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  I have added some explicit calls to `Write-Vebose` to show what does and does not get captured.  It is clear that there is a problem with getting the stream output from the `Invoke-Command` block.

Comment: I've noticed that I can redirect the verbose stream to the output stream using 4>&1 and capture the output in the results collection.  However, I would really like to just get the real verbose stream from the Invoke-Command scriptblock.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146575/how-to-capture-a-powershell-cmdlets-verbose-output-when-the-cmdlet-is-programma You can access the verbose stream $ps.streams.verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Your script block has its own verbose preference (`$VerbosePreference`). Set it to `Continue` inside script block then it should work.